# Word or phrase for becoming clumsy due to being overjoyed/happy

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, vocabulary

As the title implies, I'm trying to describe a person who is extremely happy and because of that behaves clumsily since they don't have enough attention about their surroundings.

The specific case would be that the character is in a celebration, and trips and falls, or breaks her mug banging it to others' during a toast etc. It's important to note that they're not normally clumsy at all, and these would not happen to them if their mind wasn't focused on the joy and celebration at the moment.

I was wondering if there is a word or phrase to describe this elegantly?

For example "The ____ that he was at the moment, he spilled most of his beer on the table when banging his mug to others' for the toast." or "He had a _____ , not looking where he is going and bumping into guests while running from room to room in the party."

What came to my mind was *joystruck*, or *joy drunk* but unfortunately they aren't actual words. *Having a mind over-saturated with happiness* might describe the condition, but is too long and  I was hoping a more common word/phrase exists for it.

Comment: Sounds like *punch drunk* or *wearing a silly grin*.

Comment: Unfortunately _wearing a silly grin_ only describes the facial expression not the behavior. Is _punch drunk_ used when the cause is happiness, and not actual damage to the head? @YosefBaskin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are deliriously happy (usually used as hyperbole):

> **deliriously happy**
>
> - *It's because she's so madly, deliriously happy that she wants everyone else to be happy too*.

[[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/deliriously-happy)] ...

> **delirious** [adjective]
>
> Someone who is delirious is unable to think or speak in a sensible and
> reasonable way ...

.............

> **delirious**: [(2)a] marked by uncontrolled excitement ...

[[AHD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/delirious)]

..............................................

Another possibility is to use *ecstatic* (again, usually used hyperbolically):

> **ecstasy**
>
> 1a: a state of being beyond reason and self-control
>
> 2: a state of overwhelming emotion, especially *rapturous delight* ...

[[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ecstasy)]

Comment: I think it'd be hard to convey the clumsiness through _ecstatic_, but _deliriously happy_ should work. _Giddy_ was a good candidate in my opinion too, but I think I'd go with _deliriously happy_. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Giddy** should do.  Often in phrases such as *giddy with delight* or *giddy with happiness*.

[Merriam Webster online: Giddy](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/giddy)

> 1
> a: DIZZY - *giddy from the unaccustomed exercise*
> b: causing dizziness - *a giddy height*
> c: whirling rapidly
> 2
> a: lightheartedly silly : FRIVOLOUS
> b: joyfully elated : EUPHORIC -  *was giddy with delight*

The noun *giglet* does exist, meaning a giddy girl among other things, but I think I'd steer clear of it.